# Look up a value in pandas with data frames of unequal lengths

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm continuing to work on my webscraper/data analysis project and am stuck on an items.  I want to determine how long a pet has been in the shelter.  In order to do this, I have a counter to determine the pet's running count of ID.  To see if the pet is still in the shelter or not, I want to compare my list of IDs to today's list.  The logic being, if the PetID is still in today's list, then the pet isn't adopted yet.  If it is not, we're assuming the pet has been adopted.  here is a mock up of the simplified data:

'''
[image]

...
So I'd like to compare PetID to PetIDToday and want to get the TimeToAdopt to populate as shown

But when I run the below code, I get an error that the data frames are unequal.  I understand the error but don't know how to accomplish.
can someone point me in the right direction?  Thank you all for your help

```
ShelterTime['TimeToAdopt'] = []
for i in ShelterTime['PetID']:
    if i.isin(PetID1216['PetID']):
        print(i)
       TimeToAdopt.append('N/A')
    else:
       TimeToAdopt.append(ShelterTime['TimeInShelter'])
```

Comment: Did you tried to made a `pd.Merge` with `how='left'`? Docs about [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

Comment: I think that's it!  such a quick solution...funny how it can be hard to see sometimes....thank you for the tip!

Comment: I am glad to help! Happy codding!